# Hide page for logged in Users

Tags: wordpress

I wanna do the following:
If a user is logged out, he can view the page id=10, if a user is logged in and view page id=10 he will be redirected to page id=5. I tried adding the below code into my header, but it didn't work.

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_redirect_page' );
function check_redirect_page() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 10 ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 5 ) );
    exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `wp` hook rather than `init`; WordPress won't have got far enough at `init` to know whether it's dealing with a particular page or not.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'check_redirect_page' );
```

From the [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) documentation:

> Warning: You can only use conditional query tags after the
>   posts_selection action hook in WordPress (the *wp* action hook is the
>   first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes,
>   this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are
>   using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function.

Comment: "Jaw drops" Thank you so very very much kind sir. Works perfectly with the 'wp' and with correct hook placement.